# Misalignment of a position after resizing an image with ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I want to resize several images and overlay them on a background image by using  Imagemagick.

I wrote following code.

```
convert -size 500x1000 xc:white \
-page +100+200 \( aaa.jpg -resize 50x \) \
-page +200+300 \( bbb.jpg -resize 50x \) \
..............
-layers flatten flatten_img.jpg"
```

I wanted to put the "aaa.jpg" on (100,200),
and the "bbb.jpg" on (200,300),
but the position of them were misaligned.

For example, the "aaa.jpg" was positioned on (33,66).

If I didn't resize them before doing "-page",
that is,

```
convert -size 500x1000 xc:white \
-page +100+200 aaa.jpg \
-page +200+300 bbb.jpg \
......
-layers flatten flatten_img.jpg"
```

the position of them were right.

How Can I put them in the right places ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try adding `+repage` after the `-resize 50x`

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but it doesn't work well.  When I added `+repage` after the `-resize 50x`, that is, `-page +100+200 \( aaa.jpg -resize 50x +repage \) \ `,  the image was positioned at (0,0).  Maybe, `+repage` effected on `-page +100+200` beyond the parentheses.

Comment: I can solve the problem. `convert -size 500x1000 xc:white \
\( aaa.jpg -resize 50x50 -repage +50+100 \)  \
\( bbb.jpg -resize 100x100 -repage +100+200 \) \
-layers flatten final.jpg"`

Comment: If you found a solution please post it as an answer and accept it, so that it can be useful for other users with a similar problem

Answer (score 0):

I can solve the problem.

`convert -size 500x1000 xc:white \ 
\( aaa.jpg -resize 50x50 -repage +50+100 \) \ 
\( bbb.jpg -resize 100x100 -repage +100+200 \) \ 
-layers flatten final.jpg`